# asking help for image posting

Tags: support, images, quality-filter

i want to post a problem  which is in image file.  i have upload the image file but I can not post it.
 after uploading upper question box shows this which i written in second bracket:

{ ![Untitled][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qbZy.png }

after posting it says that

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

```
It does not meet our quality standards.
```

where is my fault please help.

Comment: Try including your thoughts on the problem along with the image.

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/message-about-quality-standards , http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/quality-standards , http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714/low-quality-posts

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions

Comment: *i want to post a problem which is in image file*... Honestly? Don't.

Comment: In future, try to type your question (better user [LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). If you can't include the image, post the link & another user with a higher reputation will edit your question & add the image.

Comment: BTW the question was posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194516/a-metric-space-problems) by a different user.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think typing up the problem is that difficult (at least after you gain some practice, which could be after posting a few questions). There is a [nice tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on this site which should help you with basic of LaTeX/MathJax. Good editor is also helpful. (At least I prepare my posts in external editor before posting them here.)

If you are not willing to spend even a little time typing up the problem, how can you expect other users to spend their time with typing answers and explanations?

And even if you decide to post just the picture, I think adding link to original source (in this case probably [this one](http://www.nbhm.dae.gov.in/docs/phd-sample-2007.pdf)) would be nice - since the pdf-file seems to be readable a little better than the picture you provided.

Anyway, I've typed the question from you're picture (so that you can copy it from here - just click below on edit). Please, try to use the time I saved you by this to think at least a little about the problem and  post together with the question some your thoughts/attempts/partial solution.

> Let $(X,d_i)$, $i=1,2,3$ be the metric spaces where $X_1=X_2=X_3=\mathcal C[0,1]$ and
>   $$
> d_1(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|\\
> d_2(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)| \, dx\\
> d_3(f,g)=\left(\int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)|^2 \, dx\right)^{\frac12}.
> $$
>   Let $id$ be the identity map of $\mathcal C[0,1]$ onto itself. Pick out the true statements.
>   a. $id \colon X_1 \to X_2$ is continuous.
>   b. $id \colon X_2 \to X_1$ is continuous.
>   c. $id \colon X_3 \to X_2$ is continuous.